# Can I work with larger numbers than an unsigned long long in Arduino?

Tags: arduino-mega

I would like to use larger numbers than an unsigned long long in Arduino. Is that possible?

Comment: You should look up the BigNumber library see if it is suitable for your needs.

Comment: But... why do you need them? Usually when someone needs larger numbers then he has probably chosen the wrong algorithm...

Comment: I'll check it out.

Comment: The entire point of my project is working with large numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to use numbers bigger than an `unsigned long` on Arduino. The right one depends on the application.

**Floats and Doubles**
`float`s and `double`s types on Arduino can hold exact integers up  `2^53`. That is a very large number. They are built into the Arduino compiler.

**uint64_t**
The `uint64_t` type can hold exact integers up to `2^64`. That is a very large number. This type is built into the Arduino compiler, but note that some Arduino library functions do not have versions for this type so may need to down-convert for printing and serializing and stuff like that.

**BigNumber (or bc)**
The `BigNumber` type can represent exact numbers (integer or otherwise) limited only by available memory- but certainly hundreds of digits long on Arduino. These are extremely big numbers. This type is not built into the Arduino, but there is a nice Arduino library version available...

https://github.com/nickgammon/BigNumber

Again, this type is not supprted by the Arduino built-in library functions so  you will need to either down-convert or find `BigNumber` compatible functions for things like printing and serializing.